# using OnClick function in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I cant seem to figure out how to use it - the following has no output

```
    dom.create(
        'a',
        {
          className: 'collapse', 
          onClick: function(){
                    console.log("something");
         }
        },
        topPane.containerNode );
```

also tried

```
    function testMe(){console.log('something')}

    dom.create(
        'a',
        {
          className: 'collapse', 
          onClick: testMe
        },
        topPane.containerNode );
```

Also this:

```
    function testMe(){console.log('something')}

    dom.create(
        'a',
        {
          className: 'collapse', 
          onClick: testMe()
        },
        topPane.containerNode );
```

the last one causes testMe to be activated when the page is loaded (and not activated after click)

Comment: maybe its not called `onClick` .. the 3. version won't work no matter what. Try with `onclick` or `click` etc.

Comment: @NULL yes, this worked (using onclick instead of onClick for the first method), thank you

Comment: always remember: "onClick" with a capital C, is only for widgets. Not for normal DOM nodes. <a> (anchor tag) is a DOM element. It's not a widget. So, we need to use "onclick" without a capital C.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var link = new domConstruct.create("a", {
    href: "http://www.google.com",
    innerHTML: "Google",
    'class': "myClassHere",
    onclick: "window.open(this.href); return false;",
    onkeypress: "window.open(this.href); return false;"
});
```

or

```
var link = new domConstruct.create("a", {
    href: "http://www.google.com",
    innerHTML: "Google",
    'class': "myClassHere",
    onclick: function() { console.log("onclick"); },
    onkeypress: function() { console.log("onkeypress"); }
});
```

I think that onClick is used when dealing with dojo/dijit/dojox widgets.  But when setting events for html elements using the dojo/dom-construct, it is all lowercase (ie "onclick").

Answer (score 0):

use dom-attr(domelement,"click",function(){})
it works
dom element is the one on which the click functionality is to be set.
in your example create a using dom construct and then use the above